not able to trigger broker app for authentication
Hello everyone i need help In one of our client projects, we implemented MSAL for authentication. However, we encountered an issue where the iOS/iPad operating system uses Safari browser as its default, which is blocked by the client's Azure policy. The client has requested that we change to using Edge as the default browser for the MSAL web view, but unfortunately, the iOS/iPad operating system does not allow for changing the browser for the web view. As a result, our only option is to authenticate using the broker app (Microsoft Authenticator app). I followed all the recommended steps outlined in the MSAL documentation for the iOS/iPad operating system (documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/objc/install-and-configure-msal#ios-only-steps), but I am still unable to trigger the broker app for MSAL authentication.
here is a screenshot for the reference of issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fzfgdr0tXcg4Pg_nUI4xbVSYxTu2uPsr/view?usp=sharing
I try to trigger broker authentication (Microsoft Authentication app) using the MSAL library

Have you tried setting config.supportsBrokeredAuthentication = true in AppDelegate for MSAL authentication?

If you are seeing an error message from Microsoft login stating that "you can't get there from here" and that the edge browser is required, this is misleading. It is a default message that Microsoft shows when conditional access has failed. Authentication on iOS can't use the edge browser (and even then, edge on iOS is just safari with Microsoft ui wrapped around it). In the error page that shows there will be event IDs ("more details") that their admins can use to diagnose the problem in their conditional access rules. They will need to grant an exception for your app registration in Entra Id

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is nothing to do with the browser used for authentication.
The "You can't get there from here" message shows when conditional access has prevented access.
In this case their IT will need to grant a conditional access rule that allows authentication to your app, which is identified by the ClientID that you provide to MSAL.
If you click in "more details" you will get event IDs that IT can use to identify the issue in the conditional access logs.
Microsoft provides a guide to troubleshooting condtional access
Once there is a condtional access rule that allows the user to authenticate to your app, brokered authentication will work.
